# Is there a way to inspect a view loaded via nib to find the resource names of images in the imageViews?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, retina-display

Looking for easy way to support retina displays. It occurred to me that if I could look through a nib-loaded view and get the names of all the image resources used there, I could check if they have a corresponding retina image and load it (if it's a retina device.)

I know how to iterate through subviews after it's loaded, but I don't know how (or if you can) get the resource name set in Interface Builder. I'm trying to avoid having to set all the image names in code.

What I'd like to do (in pseudo code):

```
for subView in self.view.subviews:
    if subView is UIImageView:
        resourceName = (UIImageView *)subView.imageName
        if retinaResourceFileExists(resourceName) and isRetinaDisplay:
            (UIImageView *)subView.image = retinaImage(resourceName)
```

*(Bonus: Maybe there is a way to iterate through IBOutlet variables, but I doubt it?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Foo"];` and the device will load the @2x image automatically.

Interface Builder loads the retina image automatically, too.

Comment: Well hot damn that's awesome.

Comment: be aware that prior to iOS4 (?) you have to include the extension in the filename used in imageNamed. But it will still load the @2x images.